# Create Microsoft SQL Temp Tables (without declaring columns – like Informix)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently changed positions, and came from an Informix database environment, where I could use SQL statements to select one or more columns ... and direct the output to a temporary table.  In Informix, for temp tables, I neither had to declare the column names, nor the column lengths (only the name of a temp table) - I could simply write:

> select [columnname1, columnname2, columnname3 ..] from
>   [database.tablename] where... etc. into temp tablename1 with no log;

Note that in Informix, the temp table stores the column names by default... as well as the data types [by virtue of the data-type being stored in the temp table]. So, if the above statement was executed, then a developer could merely write:

> select columname1, columnname2, etc. from tablename1

In my experience, I found this method was very useful - for numerous reasons ('slicing/dicing' the data, using various data sources, etc.)... as well as tremendously fast and efficient.

However, now I am using Microsoft SQL Server, I have not found a way (yet) do the same.  In SQL Server, I must *declare* each column, along with its *length*:

> Create table #tablename1 ( column1 numeric(13,0) );
>
> insert into #tablename1(column1)   select [column] from
>   [database.tablename] where …
>
> [Then use the info, as needed]:
>
> select * from #tablename1 [ and do something...]
>
> Drop table #tablename1

Does anyone know of how I could do this and/or set-up this capability in Microsoft SQL Server? I looked at anonymous tables (i.e. Table-Value constructors: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)... but the guidance stated that declaring the columns was still necessary.

Thanks ahead of time
- jrd

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is :

```
select [columnname1], [columnname2], [columnname3]  into tablename1 from [database].[schema].[tablename] where...
```

prefix `tablename1` with `#` if you want the table to be temporary

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that, while you can use the syntax below:

```
SELECT col1, col2...
INTO #tempTable1
FROM TABLEA
```

You should also give your calculated columns names as well.
Such that you get:

```
SELECT col1, col2...,AVG(col9) AS avgCol9
INTO #tempTable1
FROM TABLEA
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple in sql server as well all you have to do is

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3,......  INTO #Temp
FROM Table_Name
```

This statement will Create a Temp Table on fly copying Data and DataType all over to the Temp Table. `#` sign makes this table a temporary table , you can also Create a Table by using the same syntax but with out the `#` sign, something like this

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3,......  INTO New_Table_Name
FROM Table_Name
```